# Is it right to use normal distribution to compute confidence intervals of a point in a zipf distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, gamma-distribution, scipy, numpy

I have a list of datapoints that falls within some sort of zipfian distribution or [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution):

```
population = [139212, 70192, 50000, 21000, 16000, 5000, 2000, 500, 600, 100, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

And I took a sample out of the population:

```
sample = [139212, 70192, 21000, 2000, 100, 5, 5]
```

And the mean and the standard deviation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> population = [139212, 70192, 50000, 21000, 16000, 5000, 2000, 500, 600, 100, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> sample = [139212, 70192, 21000, 2000, 100, 5, 5]
>>> np.mean(population)
20308.933333333334
>>> np.mean(sample)
33216.285714285717
>>> stats.sem(population)
10082.215934371847
>>> stats.sem(sample)
20135.645011620902
```

**Is it possible to calculate the confidence interval of each point in the sample?** E.g. at 90% confidence level, what are the lower and upper of the sample data point 139212, like some box plot of the sample datapoint.

**Is the intuition that every data point from the sample contains some sort of error bar correct ?**

- If not, what is the right way to find/compute an error bar for each point in the sample?
- If so, is using a gaussian/normal distribution to estimate the confidence interval of a point correct, i.e. is the following correct

**Is this the right computation of the confidence interval for the datapoint?** [code]:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> population = [139212, 70192, 50000, 21000, 16000, 5000, 2000, 500, 600, 100, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5]
>>> sample = [139212, 70192, 21000, 2000, 100, 5, 5]

>>> stats.norm.interval(0.9, loc=sample[0])
(139210.35514637304, 139213.64485362696)

>>> stats.norm.interval(0.8, loc=sample[0])
(139210.71844843446, 139213.28155156554)

>>> stats.norm.interval(0.7, loc=sample[0])
(139210.9635666105, 139213.0364333895)
```

So do we say, at 90% confidence, `139212` falls between `(139210.35514637304, 139213.64485362696)`. Actually what does that actually mean when we do `stats.norm.interval(0.9, loc=sample[0])`, esp. when the interval is calculated under a gaussian but the distribution of the population is zipfian? Is there any meaning to that?

It's a little crazy now that `stats.norm.interval(0.7, loc=sample[0])` is saying something like:

> Assuming that somehow there's a gaussian distribution within the sample of a zipfian distributed population and the mean happens to fall at every data point, the interval at 90% confidence of the `139212` point falls between `(139210.35514637304, 139213.64485362696)`.

Comment: @kazemakase any clues?

Comment: I have a feeling that the data you have is not gamma distributed. They don't look like `k=1` to me. What's the other parameter? Gamma is a continuous distribution.

Comment: When you take a sample mean, you can use CLT for your calculations. It works even the underlying population is not normal. You just need more samples.

Comment: The population comes from word counts so it will fall into some sort of zipfian distribution, not necessarily k=1, I'll make the edits.

Comment: Zipf this one up!

Comment: If anyone is interested, here's the context: https://twitter.com/alvations/status/844778923711852546

Comment: More specifically: https://twitter.com/AlxCoventry/status/844794108879134720